# Global solution of nonlinear Schrödinger equation via blow-up argument

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations

Set $u_0\in H^1 (\mathbb{R} ^N)$ and $1<\alpha < \frac{N+2}{N-2}$. 
I want to show that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t. if $\Vert u _0 \Vert _ {H^1} < \varepsilon$, 
then there is global solution (defined for all $t\in\mathbb{R})$ of 
$$ u_t = i (\Delta u +  \vert u \vert ^{\alpha -1} u) $$ $$ u(\cdot,0)=u_0 $$

I have proved the existence of solution (local). Now I want to prove that is in fact global. 
In order to do that, I thought to use the blow-up alternative, that is, I just have to show that 
$\Vert u \Vert _{H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)}$ is bounded, where $u$ is a $H^1-$solution. It is clear that 
 $  \Vert u \Vert _{H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)} = \Vert u \Vert _{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)} + \Vert \nabla u \Vert _{L^2\mathbb{R}^N)}$.

By the mass conservation, $\Vert u \Vert _{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}  = \Vert u _0\Vert _{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)} $. 
By the energy conservation, $ \frac{1}{2}\Vert \nabla u\Vert_{L^2} ^2 - \frac{1}{\alpha + 1} \Vert u \Vert_{L^{\alpha+1}} ^{\alpha +1} \equiv E\in\mathbb{R} $
therefore, by Sobolev embedding,
$$ \Vert \nabla u\Vert_{L^2} ^2\leq 2E + \frac{2}{\alpha + 1} \Vert u \Vert_{L^{\alpha+1}} ^{\alpha +1}\leq 2E + \frac{2C}{\alpha + 1} \Vert u \Vert_{H^1} ^{\alpha +1}$$

If I show that $\Vert \nabla u\Vert_{L^2} ^2 \leq 2E + \frac{2C}{\alpha + 1} \Vert u \Vert_{H^1} ^{\alpha +1}  \leq \text{constant}$ I finish.
I have the assumption that **$\Vert u _ 0 \Vert _{H^1}$ is small, does it implies that $\Vert u \Vert _{H^1}$ is also small?**
As I am reading on Internet, I found something called Lyapunov stability. 
Maybe is useful here, can anyone explain how could be used in this situation? Thanks in advance. Any idea is welcome!

Comment: Yes, because the set $\{t\le \varepsilon+Ct^{1+\alpha}\}$ has a bounded connected component near $0$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ and you cannot go out of it and jump to the unbounded component because $\|u\|_{H_1}$ is a continuous function of $t$.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand that. Is that related to lyapunov criteria?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "Lyapunov criteria". What I'm saying is that the $H^1$-norm $S$ of your solution always satisfies the inequality $S^2\le\varepsilon+CS^{1+\alpha}$ (sorry for the missing square in the previous remark) due to the conservation laws where $\varepsilon$ (norm squared plus energy of $u_0$) is as small as you want. The set of non-negative $S$ satisfying this inequality has 2 connected components: one bounded, in which you initially are, and one unbounded. Due to the continuity of $S$, you cannot jump from the bounded component to the unbounded, so $S$ is globally bounded.

Comment: By conservation laws, I have $$ \Vert \nabla u\Vert_{L^2} ^2\leq 2E + \frac{2}{\alpha + 1} \Vert u \Vert_{L^{\alpha+1}} ^{\alpha +1}\leq 2E + \frac{2C}{\alpha + 1} \Vert u \Vert_{H^1} ^{\alpha +1}$$ it seems that you are calling $S=\Vert \nabla u\Vert_{L^2}=\Vert  u\Vert_{H^1}$?

Comment: Just add $\|u\|_2^2$ to both sides and call $S^2=\|u\|_{H_1}^2=\|u\|_2^2+\|\nabla u\|_2^2$. Otherwise right.

Comment: Mmm and where are you using that $\Vert u_0\Vert_{H^1}$ is small?

Comment: $\varepsilon=\|u_0\|_2^2+2E$ should be small enough for the bounded component to emerge.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. By energy conservation and adding $\Vert u\Vert_{L^2}^2$, one has $$  || u||^2_{H^1}\leq 2E+||u||_{L^2} +2C/(\alpha +1)||u||^{\alpha +1}_{H^1} $$ Since $2<\alpha +1$ the above inequality shows that $|| u||^2_{H^1} $is bounded, as we want. Note that $ 2E+||u||_{L^2} $ is a constant, small or not, so $|| u||^2_{H^1}$ is bounded. So it is not needed the small initial data assumption? Where am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: "Since $2<\alpha+1$ the above inequality shows that $\|u\|_{H^1}^2$ is bounded". That's where you went wrong. The implication like that holds for free if $2>\alpha+1$ (higher power is dominated by constant plus lower power)

Comment: True... So then how can I get the boundness of $||u||_{H^1}$ from the inequality of my previous comment? I am stuck...

Comment: Erm... Have you read my stupid rants about the bounded component at all?

Comment: Oh yes,  now yes. Thanks. Finally the function $t\mapsto \Vert u\Vert_{H^1}$ is continuous so it cannot maps bounded set into unbounded ones. Where  Can I give you a positive vote for your answer? I am new here and dont know how this works.